# Angular updates irrelevant DOM element

Tags: angular

I have a very simple component in Angular (v9). The intention here is to print the current date and time upon first show of the component and after a 2 seconds delay, enable a button:Here is the code for `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  currentDate: Date;
  disabledButton: boolean = true;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.disabledButton = false;
    }, 2000);
  }

  getCurrentDate() {
    return new Date();
  }
}
```

and my code for `app.component.html`:

```
<div>
  <h5>Current date: {{ getCurrentDate() }}</h5>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disabledButton">Add user</button>
```

App on launch time:

[image]

After the delay:

[image]

My question is why after the delay, Angular also reruns the `getCurrentDate()` when the only change is the value of `disabledButton`?

Comment: I think you do not need getCurrentDate() method, use just property binding. and if you need method in string interpolation you can use custom pipe.. `{{  '' | customPipe }}`. Pipe will ease your problem and its reusable to in other component too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods in Angular templates will reevaluate every time the change detection runs. This is unperformant and can lead to unwanted behaviour as in your case. Read more about why you should avoid method calls in templates [here](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)

I'd suggest that you use the constructor or `ngOnInit()` to initialize class fields and use those in your templates. Angular's change detection will call ngOnInit after the component has been created

Comment: I think the key point here is what you said: **Methods in Angular templates will reevaluate every time the change detection runs.**

Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Such a small thing to overlook and have an entire page of items re-evaluate! thanks, I had completely forgotten about this (using angular after a long time in react and vue) and my page was slow. Moved all methods into `ngOnInit` and now page is great again